# How to make two rows insert with one button Laravel using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

i want to make two inserts in same table.

The table is based on this fields (locale, project_id(foreign key), title, caption).

And the controller looks like here:

```
public function storeTranslation(Request $request)
        {
        $projecttranslation = new ProjectTranslation();
        $projecttranslation->locale = $request->input("locale");
        $projecttranslation->project_id = $request->input("project");
        $projecttranslation->title = $request->input("title");
        $projecttranslation->caption = $request->input("caption");
        $projecttranslation->save();
        }
```

The form for the moment looks like here:

```
<div id="form2" style="display:none;" class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="col-md-"> 
      <h3>Crear nueva traduccion</h3>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormTraduccion" name="myFormTraduccion"><!--FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label name="Language">Language:</label>
              <input type="text" id="locale" name="locale" value="en" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Project">Project id:</label>
              <input type="number" id="project" name="project" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Title">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Caption">Caption:</label>
              <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Crear Traduccion" id="createtranslatesubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
              <br><br><br>

            </div>
          </form> <!-- FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE END HERE -->
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormTraduccion2" name="myFormTraduccion2"> <!--SECOND FORM TO TRANSLATE -->
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label name="title">Language:</label>
              <input type="text" id="locale" name="locale" value="es" disabled class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="order">Project id:</label>
              <input type="number" id="project" name="project" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="public">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="caption">Caption:</label>
              <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Crear Traduccion" id="createtranslatesubmit2" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
              <br><br><br>

            </div>
          </form>  <!--SECOND FORM TO TRANSLATE END HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And the ajax look like this:

```
 $("#createtranslatesubmit").click(function(){
        $("#myFormTraduccion").submit();
    });

    $("#myFormTraduccion").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUploadTranslation',
            type:'POST',
            data:$('#myFormTraduccion').serializeArray(),
            success: function(){
                $("#form2").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#form3").fadeIn(2000);
            }
        });
    });
```

This create only with the first form, the first translation.

I think i should change the view code to this (Two same inputs for each field of database):

```
<div id="form2" style="display:none;" class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="col-md-"> 
      <h3>Crear nueva traduccion</h3>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormTraduccion" name="myFormTraduccion"><!--FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label name="Language">Language:</label>
              <input type="text" id="locale" name="locale" value="en" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Project">Project id:</label>
              <input type="number" id="project" name="project" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Title">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Caption">Caption:</label>
              <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="title">Language:</label>
              <input type="text" id="locale" name="locale" value="es" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="order">Project id:</label>
              <input type="number" id="project" name="project" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="public">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="caption">Caption:</label>
              <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Crear Traduccion" id="createtranslatesubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
              <br><br><br>

            </div>
          </form> <!-- FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE END HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

That's correct? The problem to "store" the data, i think will be a foreach in controller.

And finally, i don't have any idea, how to pass the data in the ajax, with a formdata maybe?

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can't have multiple html elements with the same ID (which is true even if they are in separate forms). ID's must be unique per document. You also need to change the names to: `name="locale[]"` etc. The `[]` after the name makes it into an array. That means that `$request->input("locale")` will return an array like: `['from form 1', 'from form 2']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form, you send to the server the data of that specific form. Your approach of using multiple forms doesn't work here, because you want to send all data with only 1 specific form submit.

So you have to only create 1 form and separate the different translations with a numeric reference.

Your HTML (note the `-0` and `-1` used to separate id and name of each input element) :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormTraduccion" name="myFormTraduccion"><!--FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label name="Language">Language:</label>
          <input type="text" id="locale-0" name="locale-0" value="en" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="Project">Project id:</label>
          <input type="number" id="project-0" name="project-0" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="Title">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" id="title-0" name="title-0" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="Caption">Caption:</label>
          <input type="text" id="caption-0" name="caption-0" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="title">Language:</label>
          <input type="text" id="locale-1" name="locale-1" value="es" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="order">Project id:</label>
          <input type="number" id="project-1" name="project-1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="public">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" id="title-1" name="title-1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="caption">Caption:</label>
          <input type="text" id="caption-1" name="caption-1" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Crear Traduccion" id="createtranslatesubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
          <br><br><br>

        </div>
  </form>
```

The controller:

```
public function storeTranslation(Request $request)
{
    $projecttranslation0 = new ProjectTranslation();
    $projecttranslation0->locale = $request->input("locale-0");
    $projecttranslation0->project_id = $request->input("project-0");
    $projecttranslation0->title = $request->input("title-0");
    $projecttranslation0->caption = $request->input("caption-0");
    $projecttranslation0->save();

    $projecttranslation1 = new ProjectTranslation();
    $projecttranslation1->locale = $request->input("locale-1");
    $projecttranslation1->project_id = $request->input("project-1");
    $projecttranslation1->title = $request->input("title-1");
    $projecttranslation1->caption = $request->input("caption-1");
    $projecttranslation1->save();
 }
```

Of course, it can be easily generalized for N multiple transations and not only 2.

Comment: It's probably easier to use `name="thename[]"` instead. Then you can simply iterate through the post values and don't need to change the controller at all if you add more. You would still need to change the `id`'s to what you suggests, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This version for me is more easy, maybe cause i'm learning. But i think the version of @MagnusEriksson is more "technical". I will try the two answers, if i had some error i will put it here:) Only one answer, ajax don't change?

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer True, as long as you're using the same form id, the ajax stays the same.

Comment: Yeah but using `name="thename[]"` is harder to validate because if you miss an optional argument for the second translation and you add it for the third element, from PHP you can't easily understand if that value belongs to the second or to the third (your array will just have 2 elements). It mainly depends on your needs

Comment: It works. But i think must have fix something more. Sometimes when add the rows the increment id is like, for 'en' is 10 and for 'es' is 12. And in navigador put me duplicated key. I think they call to the function two times. It possible?

Comment: Sometimes not, always*

Comment: It is a problem in the code where you add multiple rows, without seeing it i don't know ho w to help you

Comment: The problem was the:  ` $("#createtranslatesubmit").click(function(){
        $("#myFormTraduccion").submit();
    });` , i don't need it!  Thanks for the help! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
<div id="form2" style="display:none;" class="col-md-6"> 
<div class="col-md-"> 
  <h3>Crear nueva traduccion</h3>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormTraduccion" name="myFormTraduccion"><!--FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label name="Language">Language:</label>
          <input type="text" id="locale" name="ProjectTranslation[0][locale]" value="en" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="Project">Project id:</label>
          <input type="number" id="project" name="ProjectTranslation[0][project]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="Title">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" name="ProjectTranslation[0][title]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="Caption">Caption:</label>
          <input type="text" id="caption" name="ProjectTranslation[0][caption]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="title">Language:</label>
          <input type="text" id="locale" name="ProjectTranslation[1][locale]" value="es" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="order">Project id:</label>
          <input type="number" id="project" name="ProjectTranslation[1][project]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="public">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" name="ProjectTranslation[1][title]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          <label name="caption">Caption:</label>
          <input type="text" id="caption" name="ProjectTranslation[1][caption]" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Crear Traduccion" id="createtranslatesubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
          <br><br><br>

        </div>
      </form> <!-- FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE END HERE -->
</div>
```

So you will get array of ProjectTranslation at controller side

---

Now at controller side

```
public function storeTranslation(Request $request)
    {
    $form_data = $request->get('ProjectTranslation');
    foreach($form_data as $form){
        $projecttranslation = ProjectTranslation::create($form);
        $projecttranslation->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: And please change inputs ids as it is not important for demo so, I kept as it is.